# Logarithmic differentiation with Riccati's differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, systems-of-equations

The problem of this post is a subset of Riccati's differential equation.

$$  R_{C} \left( y_{1},y_{2},y_{3},y_{4} \right) = \frac{  \left( y_{1}-y_{3} \right) \left( y_{2}-y_{4} \right)   }{ \left( y_{1}-y_{4} \right) \left( y_{2}-y_{3} \right)    }    \tag{1}  $$

$$  y_{1} ,y_{2} ,y_{3} ,y_{4} ~\text{are all the special solutions of the following Riccati's differential equation. }  $$

$$  \frac{dy}{dx} =f\left(x\right)y^{2}+ g \left( x \right) y + h \left( x \right) \tag{2}   $$

$$  f \left( x \right), g \left( x \right) , h \left( x \right) ~\text{are all known(given) as this ODE is defined }   $$

$$ R_{C}= R_{C} \left( y_{1},y_{2},y_{3},y_{4} \right) $$

The book says that the below equation can be obtained using logarithmic differentiation(s).

$$ \frac{R_{C}'}{R_{C}} =\frac{y_{1}'-y_{3}'}{y_{1}-y_{3}}+\frac{y_{2}'-y_{4}'}{y_{2}-y_{4}}-\frac{y_{1}'-y_{4}'}{y_{1}-y_{4}} -\frac{y_{2}'-y_{3}'}{y_{2}-y_{3}} \tag{3}   $$

How this can be obtained???

The final goal is to derive that a general solution of Riccati ODE can be gained as at least 3 special solutions of it are known.

What I know about logarithmic differentiation currently is as below .

$$  y:= x^x ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{This function is isolated from the eqn1}  $$

$$  \ln\left(  y \right) = \ln\left(  x^x \right)  $$

$$  \ln\left(  y \right) = x\ln\left(  x \right)  $$

$$  \frac{d}{dx} \left( \ln\left(  y \right)  \right) = \frac{d}{dx} \left( x \ln\left(  x \right)  \right)  $$

$$ \frac{1}{ y } \frac{dy}{dx} = \ln\left(x\right) + x \cdot x^{-1}$$

$$ \frac{1}{ y } \frac{dy}{dx} = \ln\left(x\right) + 1$$

$$  \frac{dy}{dx} = y \left( \ln\left(  x \right) +1 \right)  $$

$$  \frac{dy}{dx} = x^x \left( \ln\left(  x \right) +1 \right)  $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first recall what [logarithmic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation) is.
$$  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \ln f(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} f(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}  \text{.}  $$

Now replace $f$ with $R_C$, expand $R_C$ in the logarithm, and apply the [properties of logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Product,_quotient,_power,_and_root):
$$  \frac{R_C'}{R_C} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \ln R_C = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( \ln (y_1 - y_3) + \ln(y_2 - y_4) - \ln(y_1 - y_4) - \ln(y_2 - y_3) \right)  \text{.}  $$
And, of course, the sum and difference rules split this up into the four applications of differentiation of a logarithm using the chain rule.  You get the formula you recited.